# android connection with php and mysql get back the result empty

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

i am creating login activity that need connection between android system and php mysql using json to get back response and asynctask to do the connection in background but the result is always empty when i make the mysql query select using the id .

i know that the error is in the id string in the java code but i do not know how to assign this **string "id"** to take the id in the database then retrieve the needed data . if anyone can help me  i will appreciate that .

## memebers.sql

```
-- Database: `fil`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `members`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `members`
--

INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `user_name`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'cptjs', 'cpt'),
(2, 'ltpb', 'lt123');
```

## check.php

```
<?php

require_once('db_config.php'); 


// array for JSON response
$response = array();




  if(isset($_GET['pid'])){


     $pid = $_GET['pid'];  





     $query_search = "select * from members where id = '".$pid."'";  

//       $query_search = "select * from members where user_name = 'cptjs' AND password = 'cpt'";     


     $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

   if (mysql_num_rows($query_exec)>0) 
   {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec);

        $person = array();
        $response["pid"]=$result["id"];
        $person["username"]=$result["user_name"];
        $person["password"]=$result["password"];



   error_log(print_r($response, true));
   // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

   // user node
        $response["person"] = array();

        array_push($response["person"], $person);

   // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
    else
    {




    error_log(print_r($response, true));


   // no user found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No User found";


  error_log(print_r($response, true));

   // echo no users JSON
           echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else 
{
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) are missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}    
?>
```

## logCat

```
02-11 10:33:33.165: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3520): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-11 10:33:47.889: W/EGL_genymotion(3520): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-11 10:33:55.789: W/INbUFFERED Reader(3520): before  the buffered reader beguin
02-11 10:33:55.793: W/INbUFFERED Reader(3520): the JsonObject is {"message":"No User found","success":0}
02-11 10:33:55.793: W/INbUFFERED Reader(3520): before  the Parsing beguin
02-11 10:33:55.793: W/INbUFFERED  2 Reader(3520): the JsonObject is{"message":"No User found","success":0}
02-11 10:33:55.813: W/EGL_genymotion(3520): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

## JSONParser.java

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method



            if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            Log.w("INbUFFERED Reader", "before  the buffered reader beguin");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);

            }
            is.close();

            json = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 1);
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            Log.w("INbUFFERED Reader", "the JsonObject is " + jObj);
            Log.w("INbUFFERED Reader", "before  the Parsing beguin");
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);

            Log.w("INbUFFERED  2 Reader", "the JsonObject is" + jObj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

## AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.java

package pack.coderzheaven;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et, pass;
    String Username, Password;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single person url
     ******************************************************************
    private static final String url_check_login = "http://10.0.3.2/check.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PERSON = "person";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_pass = "password";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Getting complete person details in background thread
                new CheckLogin().execute();

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete person details
     * */
    class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        JSONArray productObj;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading person details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting person details in background thread
         * */

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread

            // Check for success tag

            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting person details by making HTTP request
                // Note that person details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_login,
                        "GET", params);

                // Log.e("JsonObject", json.toString());
                // check your log for json response
                // Log.d("Single person Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received person details
                    productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PERSON); // JSON Array

                }

                else {
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            if (productObj != null) {
                try {
                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    et.setText(person.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    pass.setText(person.getString(TAG_pass));

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            et.getText().toString() + pass.getText().toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Log.e("success in login", "SUCCESS IN LOGIN");

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

We connect android with php server. Then we send and retrieve data using HTTPClient. HTTPPost specifies that our request method is post. The response is stored in HTTPResponse. ‘URL’ is the actual link where JSON is present.

Then we use inputstream to get data into bytes. We need to convert byte-stream to character stream. After that we build String with the help of StringBuilder.

```
package com.techlovejump.androidphpmysql;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 JSONObject jobj = null;
 ClientServerInterface clientServerInterface = new ClientServerInterface();
 TextView textView;
 String ab;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
//start background processing 
new RetreiveData().execute();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return true;
 }
 class RetreiveData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 jobj = clientServerInterface.makeHttpRequest("http://www.yourwebsite.com/at/serverside.php");

 try {
 ab = jobj.getString("key");
 } catch (JSONException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return ab;
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(String ab){

 textView.setText(ab);
 }

 }

}
```